# Unable to change MAC using macchanger in UBUNTU 17

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, ifconfig

I've using macchanger in UBUNTU 16.04 to change the mac address of wireless lan (in order to be able to manage chromecast in my hotel).

I made a script to set my wireless lan MAC as the same MAC of the chromecast.

Lately after upgrading to UBUNTU 17, that script is not anymore working.
Firstly, i've noticed that the output of ifconfig command became different (i.e MAC address was represented by HWAdrr in UBUNTU 16 and now its name is ether)

The problem not is that, if i manually applied macchanger -m  wlo1 the MAC is changed, but once i connect to the hotel's wifi the MAC address reverts back to the original MAC address.

I reverted back to the partition were UBUNTU 16 is still installed, and i repeated the same steps using macchanger and it was successfully changed and connected to the hotel's wifi.

Is there a way to understand the changes happened to manage the wifi between UBUNTU16 to UBNTU17 ?

best regards
Thanks